# Shared folder permission vs NTFS permission

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

Can someone explain how to determine and verify whether there is lack of shared folder permission or NTFS permission e.g access denied error while connecting to shared folder either via UNC or drive mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little confusing. Windows will use the most restrictive of the two. I.E. if the share permissions give read only but the ntfs give full then you get read only. You have to look at both and determine which is the most restrictive.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please explain below query?

What is the difference between adding drive letter and omitting drive letter in the following command syntax?

net use Z: \\techdata\softwares
 &&
net use \\techdata\softwares 

Does it mean that omitting drive letter will just only allow establishing the network connection on share and will not allow viewing contents on shared resource located on server?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that is possible. The ability to do that would generally be considered a security risk. A basic principle in security matters is to not reveal information that might potentially be useful to someone attempting unauthorized access.